# How to define range for next loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, range

I'm a newbie and I'm trying to learn VBA (Sorry for any mistake in English, I'm not a native speaker). 
I am trying to solve the following assignment:
"Create a procedure that outputs the  multiplication table values ​​from 11 to 20 in Excel as shown below:"

[multiplication table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7zhJ.png)

This is my code:

```
Sub einmaleins()
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
For x = 11 To 20
For y = 11 To 20
Cells(x, y) = x * y
Next
Next
End Sub
```

It works but puts the table from K11 to S20. I need it to enter the values from A1 to J10
I have tried

```
*Range("A1:J10").FormulaR1C1 = "=ROW(RC)*COLUMN(RC)"*
```

but it doesn´t work.

Help is greatly appreciated

Comment: A1 is `Cells(1,1)` so you need to either adjust your loop, or adjust `Cells(x, y)`.

Comment: `For x = 1 to 10`, `For y = 1 to 10`, `Cells(x, y) = (x+10) * (y + 10)`. Or adjust `Cells(x, y)` using similar logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subtract `10` from each x and y coordinate.

For example, `x = 11` and `y = 11` would give `cells(1, 1)`.

```
Sub einmaleins()
    Dim x As Integer, y As Integer

    For x = 11 To 20
        For y = 11 To 20
            Cells(x - 10, y - 10) = x * y
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

In fact your formula approach is better as avoids a loop.

```
Range("A1:J10").FormulaR1C1 = "=(ROW(RC)+10)*(COLUMN(RC)+10)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go if you want more control over the code and if you plan to use this repeatedly. It will not matter even if it is 11- 20 or any other number.

Also recommend that you refer the cell with the sheet reference so that when you go on you will have no issue with referencing. EG : Sheet1.Cells (y,x)

**Here you go - The function.**

```
Function einmaleins(fNumber As Integer, lNumber As Integer) As Integer

    Dim x, y As Integer

    For x = fNumber To lNumber

        For y = fNumber To lNumber
                Sheet1.Cells(x - (fNumber - 1), y - (fNumber - 1)) = x * y
        Next
    Next

    End Function
```

**//Call the function**

```
Sub multiTable()
 Call einmaleins(11, 20)
End Sub
```

Hope this helps

Tschüss